# What is the purpose of the colgroup tag?

Tags: html, html-table, colgroup

What is the purpose of the `colgroup`tag that isn't completely superceded by the `col` tag?

I thought it should be possible to set common style properties across a column group with the `colgroup` tag and then use `col` to set individual style properties for columns within the group, but it seems using `style` on `col` overrides the `colgroup` `style` even when they refer to different properties.

Comment: Highly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41913896/should-i-use-colgroup-and-col-and-if-so-why-and-how

Comment: @j08691 I agree, but that question doesn't seem to have garnered any useful answers, so I tried to come at it from a non-accessibility angle.